# Custom extension to fit with existing theme

Tags: theme, css, frontend

I was wondering.

If someone creates an extension, lets say the extension would show recommended products then how will the developers of that extension make sure that it would fit with customer's shop theme?

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/frequently-bought-together-extension.html For example this extension.

Are extensions like this one only developed for one specific Magento theme or are they suitable for any theme, including customer's own custom theme?

And if so, how would they achieve something like this? So during the extension installation lets say, it would determine itself the theme and make correct changes so it would fit visually with the rest of the page.

Comment: Could this be achieved so that the extension would use Magento's styles.css for that? So that somewhere in the extension there are defined these classes with the exact same name as Magento has for styling. And then the extension would automatically start reading the styles attributes from Magento's styles.css according to the class name.